# Avoiding regexps abuse in generation of statements to be executed

Tags: python, python-2.x, regex, pygame, chess

I made a GPL project to read Shogi Western Notations that I made public in [GitHub](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/tree/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec). The project works perfectly on Ubuntu. Please check README.md to check requirements.

**All this code works quite well**. The basic idea was fragmenting each notated move with a long regexp, which I think is the best way to optimize the process. First, I read notated games in plain text and store every move as an element into a list:

`shogi_reader.py` -> [line 50](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/shogi_reader.py#L50)

```
movs = game_data.movs.splitlines()
```

There are also two objects that control position of pieces to determine moves. They are defined in my project in the file `managers.py`. The classes are named `coords_manager()` and `matrix_manager()`. coords_manager class controls a list of coords for every kind of piece and controls the revertion of coords if R key is pressed. matrix_manager controls a matrix of boolean values to determine if a square is owned by a piece or not. `lamesa` is an instance of coords_manager(), which controls the arrays of coords of pieces and reverts the pieces' coords, which are a property of the class.

The program works in two steps:

**1-** It reads the notation and calculates how to store the data into a format revertible backwards for the user using `matchobj.group(n)`. (`shogi_reader.py`, [line 69](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/shogi_reader.py#L69):)

```
reg = re.compile('^\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\+?[P|L|N|S|G|K|R|B](\d[a-i])?)([-|x|*])(\d[a-i][=|\+]?)$')
error_cnt = 0

for move in movs:
    move_to_add = None
    kind = ''
    action = None
    promoting = False
    piece_respawn = ''
    piece_x = 0
    piece_y = 0
    frag = reg.match(move)
    destiny = [lamesa.coords_x[frag.group(5)[0]],lamesa.coords_y[frag.group(5)[1]]]
    destiny_h = frag.group(5)
    if len(frag.group(5)) > 2:
        if frag.group(5)[2] == '+':
            promoting = True
    if (len(frag.group(2)) > 1 and frag.group(2)[0] != '+') or (len(frag.group(2)) > 2 and frag.group(2)[0] == '+'):
        if frag.group(2)[0] == '+':
            kind = frag.group(2)[0:2]
            piece_x = lamesa.coords_x[frag.group(2)[2]]
            piece_y = lamesa.coords_y[frag.group(2)[3]]
        else:
            kind = frag.group(2)[0]
            piece_x = lamesa.coords_x[frag.group(2)[1]]
            piece_y = lamesa.coords_y[frag.group(2)[2]]
    else:
        kind = frag.group(2)
    if frag.group(4) == 'x':
        action = 1
    elif frag.group(4) == '*':
        action = 2
    elif frag.group(4) == '-':
        action = 0
    # [...]
```

**2-** The canvas is loaded, and the pieces are drawn into the shogi board. The notated game then can be played with arrows OR (A and D keys), and revert the board with R.

Once the second step begins, a list with the formatted moves is stored in `history_pos` list and then replayed with following functions assigned to arrow keys. *This is the part of the algorythm where the regexp abuse takes place*(Lines [84](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/funciones.py#L84), [94](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/funciones.py#L94) and [141](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/funciones.py#L141)):

`funciones.py` -> [Line 65](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/funciones.py#L65)

```
def move_forward():
    global pos, history
    output = ''
    if pos < len(history):
        if history[pos][2] == 2:
            #In this case,
            # history[pos] structure -> [[kind_of_piece,counter_to_assign_id], destiny_coords, action, promoting, piece_respawn]
            statem = 'lamesa.lista_'+history[pos][0][0]+'['+(str)(history[pos][0][1])+']=['+(str)(lamesa.coords_x[history[pos][1][0]])+','+(str)(lamesa.coords_y[history[pos][1][1]])+']'
            exec statem
            output = 'lamesa.r'+history[pos][0][0]+' -= 1'
        else:
            # Standard case,
            # history[pos] structure -> [code_statement_to_select_piece, coords_sum, action, promoting, piece_respawn]
            statem = 'lamesa.'+history[pos][0]+'[0]+='+(str)(history[pos][1][0]*lamesa.reverted)
            exec statem
            statem = 'lamesa.'+history[pos][0]+'[1]+='+(str)(history[pos][1][1]*lamesa.reverted)
            exec statem
            if history[pos][3] == True: #Handle piece_promotion==True
                #TODO Simplify this task avoiding the regexp abuse
                prueba = re.match('^.*\[(.*)\]$', history[pos][0])
                statem = 'prueba2=lamesa.'+history[pos][0]
                exec statem
                statem = 'del lamesa.'+history[pos][0]
                exec statem
                prueba4 = re.match('^.*_(.*)\[.*\]$', history[pos][0])
                statem = 'lamesa.lista_s'+prueba4.group(1)+'['+prueba.group(1)+']=['+(str)(prueba2[0])+','+(str)(prueba2[1])+']'
                exec statem
        if history[pos][4] != '': #Piece captured that has to be respawn backwards
            # TODO Avoid regexp abuse
            frag = re.match('^(lista_(.*)\[.*\])=\[.*,.*\]$', history[pos][4])
            theobj = frag.group(1)
            piece = frag.group(2)
            if len(piece) == 3:
                piece = piece[1:]
            if piece[-1] == 'b':
                piece = piece[:-1]+'n'
            else:
                piece = piece[:-1]+'b'
            statem = 'del lamesa.'+theobj
            exec statem
            output = 'lamesa.r'+piece+' += 1'
        pos += 1
        previous_highlight(pos)
    return output
```

`funciones.py` -> [Line: 129](https://github.com/SebasSBM/shogi_reader/blob/097efbfb1f57ec46a688877ecdb6f1d7db6224ec/funciones.py#L129)

```
def move_back():
    global pos, history
    output = ''
    if pos > 0:
        pos -= 1
        if history[pos][2] == 2:
            statem = 'del lamesa.lista_'+history[pos][0][0]+'['+(str)(history[pos][0][1])+']'
            exec statem
            output = 'lamesa.r'+history[pos][0][0]+' += 1'
        else:
            if history[pos][3] == True:
                #TODO Avoid regexp abuse
                prueba = re.match('^.*\[(.*)\]$', history[pos][0])
                prueba4 = re.match('^.*_(.*)\[.*\]$', history[pos][0])
                statem = 'prueba2=lamesa.lista_s'+prueba4.group(1)+'['+prueba.group(1)+']'
                exec statem
                statem = 'lamesa.'+history[pos][0]+'=['+(str)(prueba2[0])+','+(str)(prueba2[1])+']'
                exec statem
                statem = 'del lamesa.lista_s'+prueba4.group(1)+'['+prueba.group(1)+']'
                exec statem
            statem = 'lamesa.'+history[pos][0]+'[0]-='+(str)(history[pos][1][0]*lamesa.reverted)
            exec statem
            statem = 'lamesa.'+history[pos][0]+'[1]-='+(str)(history[pos][1][1]*lamesa.reverted)
            exec statem
        if history[pos][4] != '':
            frag = re.match('^lista_(.*)\[.*\]=\[.*,.*\]$', history[pos][4])
            piece = frag.group(1)
            if len(piece) == 3:
                piece = piece[1:]
            if piece[-1] == 'b':
                piece = piece[:-1]+'n'
            else:
                piece = piece[:-1]+'b'
            exec 'lamesa.'+history[pos][4]
            output = 'lamesa.r'+piece+' -= 1'
        previous_highlight(pos)
    return output
```

`history` list's elements have two different formats depending on the kind of move:

- Normal move:

  `[code_statement_to_select_piece, coords_sum, action, promoting, piece_respawn]`
- Drop:

  `[[kind_of_piece,counter_to_assign_id], destiny_coords, action, promoting, piece_respawn]`

When action==2, the structure of history[pos] elements is different in order to send data that is needed in order to revert the drop move. This transformation is made to obtain a state that can be calculated forward and backwards for the position and state of pieces:

The way I structured the algorythm forced me to make some abuse of regexps in these fragments of code.

There are the `move_forward()` and `move_back()` functions, which performs a change on the properties of coords_manager() and matrix_manager() objects which objective is to keep the pieces' state. I had to make some abuse of regexps in these lines to make the operations I needed on the state.

I think I should change the structure of objects inside `history_pos` list in order to prevent abuse of regexps, but I don't have good ideas for it.

Am I really abusing of regexps here? If so, which structure changes on objects inside `history_pos` list would be needed to prevent the abuse of regexps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the "regexp abuse" concern, you also have a problem with the use of `exec`.  Actually, I would consider them both to be symptoms of a deeper problem: your modelling is underdeveloped.

Specifically, the problem is that your data are ["stringly typed"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped).

A better design would be for the parser to return a list of `Move` objects.  Here's a rough idea:

```
class Move
    def __init__(self, from_coord, to_coord, promoted_to=None):
        self.from = from_coord
        self.to = to_coord
        self.piece = None
        self.captured_piece = None
        self.promoted_to = None

    def do_move(self, board):
        self.piece = board.get_piece(self.from_coord)
        self.captured_piece = board.get_piece(self.to_coord)
        if self.captured_piece is not None:
            board.remove_piece(self.to_coord)
        board.remove_piece(self.from_coord)
        board.put_piece(self.to_coord, self.promoted_to or self.piece)

    def undo_move(self, board):
        board.remove_piece(self.to_coord)
        board.put_piece(self.from_coord, self.piece)
        if self.captured_piece is not None:
            board.put_piece(self.to_coord, self.captured_piece)
```

The `shogi_reader` would return a list of these `Move` objects, and you can play and unplay the moves as necessary by calling `do_move()` or `undo_move()`.

Comment: Looks like a good way to prevent abuse of regexps and exec instruction. I'll check it out.

Comment: There are four managers in managers.py: coords_manager(), sprites_manager(), matrix_manager() and input_manager(). The 1st and 3rd control the logic on squares and piece's coords, so making a Move class that handles it in a cleaner way may be factible. Late or soon, I will try it out.

Comment: I encourage you to ask about `coords_manager` in a separate question.

Comment: Just adding information about what I'm planning to do to perform a `Move` class. I'm not sure if you mean there's a problem with `coords_manager()`

Comment: I'm suggesting that `coords_manager` could use a lot of improvement.

Comment: I thought so. I guess you are right, so, late or soon, I will try to make a sepparate question about coords_manager()

Comment: [Follow-up question posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96707/9357)

Answer (score 2):

Considering just your regex…

> ```
> reg = re.compile('^\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\+?[P|L|N|S|G|K|R|B](\d[a-i])?)([-|x|*])(\d[a-i][=|\+]?)$')
> ```

I see a few problems.

- It's good practice to use `r'raw strings'` for any non-trivial regex, to prevent backslashes from having additional special meaning.
- The use of character classes is incorrect.  Inside a character class, the "or" is implicit.  That is, `[PLNSGKRB]` means the same as `(?:P|L|N|S|G|K|R|B)`.
- Inside a character class, some characters, such as `+`, are taken literally.  You don't need to put a backslash in front.

```
reg = re.compile(r'^\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\+?[PLNSGKRB](\d[a-i])?)([-x*])(\d[a-i][=+]?)$')
```

For readability, I suggest taking advantage of [`re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) and `(?P<name>…)` groups.

```
reg = re.compile(r"""^\s*(?P<move_num>\d+)
                     \s*-\s*(?P<piece>\+?[PLNSGKRB](?P<from>\d[a-i])?)
                     (?P<action>[-x*])
                     (?P<to>\d[a-i][=+]?)$""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. When I have somemore time I'll use this information to make the code more readable and test your VERBOSE version to see if it keeps accuracy.

Comment: Anyway, the main issues with regexps abuse are in `move_forward()` and `move_back()` functions (`funciones.py` file)